# I want to get rid of Ubuntu 11.04 and get xubuntu 12.04, but disk won't work?

Tags: 11.04, xubuntu

I have been using Ubuntu 11.04 for quite some time know, but i've noticed that my laptop was running slowly. So i decided to get a different operating system that was similar to ubuntu, so I ran into Xubuntu which i've heard was a bit better for older computer, but still was in the linix name. So what im asking for are some instructions on how to get rid of ubuntu and how to install xubuntu. 
Thank you for any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xubuntu is a form of ubuntu, it just has a differn't set of applications installed by default. That said, installing from scratch might be wise as you are two version behind.

If you want to reinstall, then download the installable live cd from here: http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/

and burn it to a CD and install like you did with your existing ubuntu.

If you do not want to upgrade to 12.04, or just want to try out xubuntu from your existing setup, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

and then log out and choose it from the login manager. (I forget where it is on 11.04, but on 12.04 its the icon next to your name)

Comment: Thanks i'll try the cd one more time, but if that doesnt work ill go with the second option.

Comment: you can upgrade your existing install by using the update manager.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Comment: one more thing, I don't know how to install xubuntu, my uncle installed this ubuntu when i went to his house that is in a different state. Any steps i could get please. Thank you